# Is my question about altimeters, as edited, eligible to be reopened?

Tags: support, status-completed

Is my edit about altimeters enough to reopen the question?[What are the pros and cons of a digital altimeter over an analog altimeter for backpacking?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9451/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-a-digital-altimeter-over-an-analog-altimeter-for-b)

If not, what do you suggest?  I need some technical advice fairly soon.  Thank you.